# Как написать скрипт, который хранит в базе даных url сайтов ?

Tags: php, javascript

Как написать скрипт, который хранит в базе даных url сайтов и если url уже есть в базе, выдает сообщение "Что он уже есть" при вводе в форму?

Я понимаю, что пример простой (для опытного программера 15 минут) нужна небольшая таблица и скрипт обработчик? Но у меня нет времени сейчас. Буду благодарен за идеи и советы. )

Comment: Что за URL и откуда они берутся, скажите!

Comment: URL сайтов - необходим учет, над какими сайтами произведены работы, чтоб не запутаться. В голове, ну 10 сайтов еще запомните, а если их 100, 1000 - это нереально, поэтому пусть php бот это проверяет! Ему ведь не сложно, это всего-лишь программа ;)

Comment: Короче, из хэшкода пытаются сделать филиал freelance.ru

У вас времени нет, или все-таки денег? ;)

Answer (score 2):

1. Создаёте базу, в ней таблицу к примеру "url" (id, url).
2. Создаёте файл - конфигурации(прим. config.php) в него вложить данные для подключения к базе данных.
3. Создаёте файл - сам скрипт, в него подключаете файл конфигурации, в нём создаёте форму - добавление в базу новых урл. Так же при добавлении - поставить проверка запросом на данный урл - **SQL(WHERE url = $url)**.

Comment: Если, чтобы выдавался (есть или нет урл) при введении его в input формы. То пользуемся jQuery.

Comment: Благодарю за алгоритм, уже начал писать:)

Answer (score 1):

Давайте начнем с того что скрипт НЕ может хранить что-то в базе.

Если вам надо сохранять URL в базе я вижу 2 подхода:

- Перед записью URL ищете его в базе и если нет - вносите
- Делаете в базе ключ UNIQUE для поля с URL, а потом проверяете записалось или нет

Как это конкретно делать смотрите на [php.ru](http://www.php.ru/) там есть документация

Answer (score 1):

Подробней разверну ответ Сергея. После создания ключа UNIQUE для поля URL следует выполнить следующий запрос:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO table (url) VALUES '" . $url . "'", $db);
```

Затем в зависимости от

```
mysql_affected_rows($query);
```

выводить сообщение об успешном добавлении (1), или неудаче (0).

Comment: Sambady, а в переменную $url я как понимаю можно передавать ссылку методом POST ; 

А потом уже выполнять запрос к БД :

$query = mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO table (url) VALUES '" . $url . "'", $db);
И если она там есть выводить TRUE или  FALSE 
Если это так так то скрипт уже готов)
Большое спасибо  Sambady за такой простой и ясный ответ!

Comment: Можно узнать зачем в запросе IGNORE?

Comment: Без него при совпадении урл выпадет исключение при добавлении данных.